# Adding a widget in scrollView programmatically

Tags: android

I am having trouble adding a view in the scrollview. The structure of my xml is

```
// xml_layout.xml
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    >
        <LinearLayout>
            <ListView
            ...
            />
        </LinearLayout>

    ******Here I am trying to add an item *********
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I am trying to add a textview at the bottom programmatically as follows.

```
        TextView v = new TextView(getActivity());
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        v.setText("TEST View");
        v.setLayoutParams(params);

        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.xml_layout, null).findViewById(R.id.container);
        container.addView(v, 1);
```

The goal I am trying to achieve is making a tablelayout that contains two columns with the title and listview in the second column. Before I do this, I tried to display a simple textview so that I know I can add a widget. I have tried many different ways but did not work. Is there something wrong with my code??

Answer (score 0):

you must first verify that your LinearLayout 'container' is 'vertical ' orientation, and...

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
container.addView(v);
```